# VB Function InStr() Equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm converting VB to C++. I don't know how to convert InStr() to C++.
I have manged Left() but InStr() is not available in C++. Can Someone please tell me how to convert InStr() to C++.

```
Public Function CW_Name(ByVal alIndex As Long) As String
     If Not Fb_ValidIndex(alIndex) Then Exit Function
     '-->DT - 08/10/11 - SIT#47953 - Truncate string on Chr(0)
     Dim liMark As Integer
     liMark = InStr(1, CurrentMat.Description, Chr(0))
     If liMark Then
          CW_Name = Left(CurrentMat.Description, liMark - 1)
     Else
          CW_Name = CurrentMat.Description
     End If
     '<--DT - 08/10/11 - SIT#47953 - Truncate string on Chr(0)
End Function
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Std::string.find(myString.begin(), myString.end(), 'F') != std::string::npos

Comment: Of course it exists http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: Are you using a `CString` or a `std::string` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a `CString`, it has a `.Find()` method which does what you want.

Note in VB a string's index begins at 1, but in C++ and MFC begins at 0. If `CString.Find()` fails, it returns `-1`

Documentation: [CString::Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx#cstringt__find)

Answer (score 1):

```
int instr(string istring, string tofind){
    if (istring.find(tofind)!=istring.npos){
        return istring.find(tofind)+1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be useful to include some explanation and/or references to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

no need to reinvent the wheel... c++ has a String object with find method that allows you to get the same behaviour.

here is how to use it and here the [docu](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

```
  std::string str ("There are two needles in this haystack with needles.");
  std::string str2 ("needle");

  // different member versions of find in the same order as above:
  std::size_t found = str.find(str2);
  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "first 'needle' found at: " << found << '\n';
```

Comment: It seems to me OP is using a `CString`, not a `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

The standard library of C++ has function std::string::find with different overloads wherein you can search for a substring within a string and a character too,by using the required overload.

Note: In case its a CString,you can use CString::Find,the overloads are almost similar

Comment: It seems to me OP is using a `CString`, not a `std::string`